# No SQL scripts during MSI installer on Japanese Windows XP

Tags: sql, windows-xp, windows-installer, installshield

we have to install our product with InstallShield on several systems. During installation we have to execute some SQL scripts, this works properly in nearly every case.
Except a Japanese Windows XP we have (x86 with SP3).
(It doesn't fail on every machine, just on some).

First it happen that, even the installation was running and end without an error output, the application was not running because of missing database and SQL instance settings.
In the MSI I first found no problem.

I found registry entries which has expand the log file a little more, and because of that I was able to see an error on one place.
The installer is not possible to extract the SQL scripts out of the installer temp files.

This is how a working installation looks:

```
MSI (s) (D0:CC) [06:32:27:394]: Invoking remote custom action. DLL: C:\Windows\Installer\MSI2B17.tmp, Entrypoint: ISSQLServerCosting
1: Beginning SQL Server Costing Process... 
1: Reading the SQL script data from ISSQLConnection table... 
1: ISSQLRequirement table does not exist... 
1: ISSQLRequirement table does not exist... 
1: Finished SQL Server Costing Process... 
1: Setting Costing Info Location  ISSQLServerInstall : C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Temp\~2B44.tmp 
MSI (s) (D0!9C) [06:32:27:465]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding ISSQLServerInstall property. Its value is 'C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Temp\~2B44.tmp'.
...
```

(There are some more "Setting Costing Info Location" lines with "PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding".)

But on the not working Japanese XP it looks like:

```
MSI (s) (8C:E0) [14:51:37:031]: Invoking remote custom action. DLL: C:\WINDOWS\Installer\MSI30.tmp, Entrypoint: ISSQLServerCosting
1: Beginning SQL Server Costing Process... 
1: Reading the SQL script data from ISSQLConnection table... 
1: ISSQLRequirement table does not exist... 
1: An unhandled exception occurred in ExtractScriptFile() 
1: An unhandled exception occurred in ExtractScriptFile() 
1: An unhandled exception occurred in ExtractScriptFile() 
1: An unhandled exception occurred in ExtractScriptFile() 
1: ISSQLRequirement table does not exist... 
1: An unhandled exception occurred in ExtractScriptFile() 
1: Finished SQL Server Costing Process... 
1: Setting Costing Info Location  ISSQLServerInstall :  
1: Setting Costing Info Location  ISSQLServerUninstall :
```

There we see unhandled exceptions and no result for the actions.

1. In a MS help page I saw for "unhandled exceptions" that this may caused by errors in the netapi32.dll, so I tried to replace it with another version. This has not changed anything, further was during installation the newer version replaced by the original one anyhow.
2. There are the same amount of temp files during installation (in %temp%) which will be created on working systems as well.
3. On a virtual machine with the Japanese Windows XP it works normally, I find no difference.
4. All works find and without errors, just the missing SQL scripts happen on that system. The installation itself does not end with an error.

I'm out of ideas :-/ Please help

Comment: Is this an InstallScript custom action? The COM/DCOM support for the InstallShield script engine was historically fragile, that's all I can suggest for now. Something is failing to get the script out of the MSI to run, based on the API name.

Comment: No its not Custom. The SQL scripts and its settings are configured in InstallShield in this SQL section. The only think I saw so far is that the msi.dll is 4.5.6001.22299 on the Machine where it doesn't work. On the working machines its the 4.5.6001.22159.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out, it works if I change the "TEMP" and "TMP" paths to anything else.
I don't know why the original temp paths has problems, temp files can be written and deleted, only extracting of the SQL files (or check in which temp script files are located) failes.

I compared with a working machine and the system user has no different rights or something.